# How to configure mutt to work with POP and Horde Webmail Service?

Tags: mutt

I have installed mutt from repositories and somehow configured from scratch `.muttrc` configuration file for Gmail and its working hassle free. But, I would like to use mutt for my office mail.

We Usually use Horde Webmail Service and would like to use POP also. But I don't know the configuration for it - the folder path and all.

Answer (score 0):

For webmail server you have install **msmtp**

Run `vi .msmtprc`

```
#######webmail account
defaults
logfile ~/msmtp.log

account webmail
auth on
host **************
from ****email address*******

auth on

tls on
```

Please comment below three line

```
#tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
#tls on
#tls_trust_file /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Equifax_Secure_CA.crttls_certcheckoff

user ********email address********

password *****

port ****
```

and save the file

Run `vi .muttrc`

```
set from="*****email address********"

set sendmail="/usr/bin/msmtp"
```

and save the file

Run `vi .mailrc`

```
set sendmail="/usr/bin/msmtp"
set message-sendmail-extra-arguments="-a webmail"
```

and give execute permissions for `.mailrc` and `.muttcr`  like (`-rw-rw-r--`).
I hope it will work.